# Segmentation fault when accessing a xmlNode with libxml2 only on raspberry pi

Tags: c, struct, raspberry-pi, libxml2

I have written a small library in C which reads XML results from a web API, parses them and writes the results into some structs.

On my MAC as well as in a Ubuntu VM the library works fine for me.

Today I tried to use this library on my Raspberry Pi and have been facing a strange problem:

```
xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;
xmlChar* value = NULL;
//int i;

for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node != NULL; cur_node = cur_node->next)
{

    if(cur_node == NULL)
    {
        DEBUGXML("cur_node is NULL.\n");
    }
    else {
        DEBUGXML("cur_node not NULL.\n");
        if(cur_node->name != NULL)
        {
            DEBUGXML("cur_node->name: %s\n", cur_node->name);
        }
        else 
        {
            DEBUGXML("cur_node->name is NULL.\n");
        }

    }
```

As you can see I have a pointer cur_node and to some recusive parrsing. This code is part of a function which i call recursively at the end if it with handing over the result of `cur_node->children`.

on my raspberry pi, the program exits with segmentation fault message on every point where i try to access a member of the struct xmlNode, like `cur_node->name` or `cur_node->type`.

So this one works:

```
if(cur_node == NULL)
```

But at this line

```
if(cur_node->name != NULL)
```

The program quits with segfault message.

I can substitute name with type or any other member of the struct.

Does any one have an idea?

**UPDATE:**

I did some additional tests and found out the following:

I can use my functions fine with a static defined xml string on every platform.
Therefore i´m now thinking that the difference could be the xml string, which i get from a curl call.

Because the header if the xml call contains some quotation marks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

could there be any problem for the libxml2 to parse the string with normal (double) quotation marks?

Comment: You should simply run it in the debugger.

Comment: don´t have a debugger installed on my pi

Answer (score 0):

It seems that cur_node points to an invalid address. This is the most probable reason you are past the `NULL` check and then the code crashes. For start, you have to check where `cur_node->next` gets its value and whether this is initialized to NULL.

Comment: pointing to an invalid address is the basic information when you get the segmentation fault message. Because i´m using libxml2 the first time i´m not very familiar with it and i cannot understand why the members of the xmlNode struct should be pointing to an invalid address or what can i do to prevent this.

Comment: Yes I agree. But I would still recommend to check whether everything is initialized (to NULL) since this random crash often indicate an initialization issue.

Comment: @solick There's not much you can do except code it so this doesn't happen. What that means is that somewhere in the code(could be anywhere, could be a buffer overflow, could be failure to check a return value, typo, using the libxml2 api wrong etc.) your code has a bug - which we can't help with unless we see the code or have a way to debug your program

Comment: i will prepare the code and upload it to sourceforge and will provide you the link so that you can check it.

Comment: did some test on my own and was now able to create with a test string a working version for raspberry. Therefore i need to go more intensive through my code to check, where the problem lies. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with an smaller XML, probably you're running out of memory.